# Backing up data from DELL Perc4 LSI controller

Tags: dell, scsi

We had a failure of a critical server this morning. Most likely the PSU failed, now we need to Backup the data to another system.
The server in question is a DELL 2800, featuring a built-in PERC4E SCSI controller with two hard disks (RAID1).
Since the Server is nearly nine years old, we don't have any replacement parts at hand.

Is there an easy and conveniant way to get the data off the disks?

Comment: `1.` Does this server have only a single PSU? If so, why? `2.` Are you saying that you don't have backups of the data on this server? `3.` Have you confirmed that the PSU is dead? If so, why not purchase a replacement PSU, get the server back up and running, and set up appropriate backups?

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm answering for my colleague who is already out of office. A firm called us this morning to get the data from a broken system to a new server. The backup seems to be incomplete. We tried to find a compatible LSI controller but didn't find reliable informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to find another PE 2800 where we could scavange the PSU to revive the faulting server. We tried to get one from DELL official store, but they issued 3 days of shipping. Our customer needed the server back and online the next day, so sadly this was no option.
Thank you for information and suggestions though, we will have a serious talk with the customer about his backup strategy.